# Draw 2D line with vector and start point

Tags: java, graphics, 2d, raytracing

I am making a 2D game with java GUI. I have basic lights using this algorithm http://ncase.me/sight-and-light/ . I cast rays and get the closeset hit point. My problem is that i check each ray with each wall. In order to speed it up i made the map in sectors. Each sector is (20x20 pixels). Basically it is two dimentional array and each sector contains reference to the wall in it or passing trough it. I cast a ray using a start point and a direction vector and i want to make it go trough sectors. I first thought using the Bresenham's algorithm, but it is only for a line with start and end point. The ray I cast doesn't have end point, it is just going untill it hits a wall and thats why it isn't working for me. Basically it just sums up to drawing a line with start point and a direction vector. Can somebody help ? Thanks in advance !